# Вопрос о php изменить вывод стандартного поля

Tags: php, opencart

В опенкарте стоял:

```
            if (!empty($firstname['required'])) {
                if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) > 32)) {
                    $json['error']['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
                }
            }
```

Показывало сообщение, заменил на:

```
if (!empty($firstname['required'])) {
  if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) > 32)) {
    $json['error']['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
    // добавляем CSS класс 'error' к полю 'firstname'
    $this->document->addStyle('.input-text[name="firstname"] { border: 1px solid red; }');
  }
}
```

Кто подскажет, что делать, чтобы сработало? Помогите, пожалуйста.